# AndroidTv and Smartphone in one app / Different launcher

Tags: android, android-fragments, manifest, launcher, leanback

I am writing an application that will serve for tv and smartphone. For now I just want to differentiate the main screen depending on the device. 
I have placed fragments, and that are therefore arranged differently according to the device. 
But when I launch the application on TV, it is not tvActivity that is launched but the mainActivity

Also, i have 2 launcher in the manifest, one

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

and the other

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Here is my code :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.jamesp.fragmenttest">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="false" />


    <!--Unsupported TV hardware features-->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.faketouch"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor"
        android:required="false"/>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:banner="@mipmap/ic_launcher">



        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity android:name=".TvActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

TvActivity :

```
public class TvActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tv);

    }
}
```

MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = "TAG";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         UiModeManager uiModeManager = (UiModeManager) getSystemService(UI_MODE_SERVICE);
         if (uiModeManager.getCurrentModeType() == Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_TELEVISION) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Running on a TV Device");
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_tv);
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Log.d(TAG, "Running on a non-TV Device");
        }
    }
}
```

With this test I can differentiate and therefore choose the right layout, but I don't understand why Tv is launching MainActivity.

Thanks

Comment: probably you need to create a layout resuce folder with support tv screen sizes try read the documentation at this link https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thanks for the link ! Actually I just noticed something, if i reverse the order of the activities in the manifest, it's the first who count. If I place TvActivity before MainActivity both devices (tv and smartphone) will launch TvAcitivty. 
So how to make a difference? Is it possible to have multiple "launchedActivity" ?

Comment: I never try make na app with two launcher activitys, when I need a diferent layout in diferent screens i do what Google recomends but you can try search in Google.

Comment: I am facing same issues. Having 2 launcher will launch the first one in manifest. Would appreciate if anyone comes up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use this as your manifest. It will work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="true" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:banner="@drawable/app_icon_your_company"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon_your_company"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/app_icon_your_company"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DetailsActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".PlaybackOverlayActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".BrowseErrorActivity" />
</application>
```